# import & export may only appear at the top level - CRA React App with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, create-react-app

This has been asked before, but I believe my context is different. I am running a React app configured with `Create React App` run with the `--typescript` flag.

I tried to configure eslint, prettier and husky to run a precompile script, and things started going wrong.

The error I am getting is: `'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level` and it related to this line in the following component: 
`export default SignUp`

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { compose } from 'recompose'

import { withFirebase } from '../Firebase'
import * as ROUTES from '../../constants/routes'

const SignUp = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>SignUp</h1>
    <SignUpForm />
  </div>
)

interface Props {
  firebase: any
}

const Admin = ({ firebase }: Props) => {

const SignUpFormData = ({ firebase, ...props }: Props) => {
  const initialState = {
    username: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    repeatPassword: '',
  }

  const stateReducer = (state, update) => ({ ...state, ...update })
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(stateReducer, initialState)
  const [error, setError] = React.useState({})

  const formIsInvalid =
    state.password !== state.repeatPassword ||
    state.password === '' ||
    state.username === '' ||
    state.email === ''

  const onSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const { username, email, password } = state

    firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(res => {
        return firebase
          .database()
          .ref(`users/${res.user.uid}`)
          .set({
            username,
            email,
          })
      })
      .then(() => {
        dispatch(initialState)
        props.history.push(ROUTES.HOME)
      })
      .catch(error => setError(error))
  }

  const handleChange = ({ currentTarget: { name, value } }) => {
    dispatch({ [name]: value })
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <input
        name="username"
        value={state.username}
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="Full name"
      />
      <input
        name="email"
        value={state.email}
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="Email"
      />
      <input
        name="password"
        type="password"
        value={state.password}
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="Password"
      />
      <input
        name="repeatPassword"
        type="password"
        value={state.repeatPassword}
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="Repeat password"
      />
      <button disabled={formIsInvalid} type="submit">
        Sign Up
      </button>
      {error && <p>{error.message}</p>}
    </form>
  )
}

const SignUpLink = () => (
  <p>
    Don't have an account yet? <Link to={ROUTES.SIGN_UP}>Sign Up</Link>
  </p>
)

const SignUpForm = compose(
  withRouter,
  withFirebase,
)(SignUpFormData)

export default SignUp

export { SignUpForm, SignUpLink }
```

I tried deleting the eslint entries from my [package.json](https://pastebin.com/z51AyfNT), deleting `yarn.lock`, removing node_modules and re-installing deps, but no joy.

Does anyone have any suggestions on where to begin with debugging, am lost?

Any more info needed, please shout.
Thanks so much.

**Edit**
To also note, I originally wrote the auth part of the app in standard js, with a view to learn JS, and these issues happened while I was in the process of converting the app to Typescript files, so I have a mix of `.js` and `.tsx`. I'm not sure if that's relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I got it, is just a missing a closing curly bracket.

Probably here:

```
const Admin = ({ firebase }: Props) => {
```

is not closed.

Comment: That's embarrassing, that is pasted in buy accident from a different component. It doesn't even belong in that file :( Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to export a method from one file to another.

You can directly add the export keyword like below:

```
export const SignUpLink = () => (
  <p>
    Don't have an account yet? <Link to={ROUTES.SIGN_UP}>Sign Up</Link>
  </p>
)

export const SignUpForm = compose(
  withRouter,
  withFirebase,
)(SignUpFormData)
```

If not, you can have module.exports at the end of the file as below:

```
module.exports = {
 SignUpForm, SignUpLink
}
```

I would recommend you to take a look at this [link](https://itnext.io/great-import-schism-typescript-confusion-around-imports-explained-d512fc6769c2). It might definitely help.

If you're using typescript please do add linting rules, that will be a lifesaver many times.